# Azure AD B2C - Unable to call MS Graph API or Azure AD Grap API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have an azure ad b2c with 2 custom policies, one for unified sign in/up page and another for password reset.

When i create an account and login, im unable get a successfull response from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`, from which i get the following error:

`AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'.
Correlation ID: 6ec76033-f72e-405d-ba1a-04c7534a571e
Timestamp: 2018-08-21 00:56:07Z
|interaction_required`

I'm making the request with the following code (using MSAL.js and axios):

```
    const config = {
      tenant: 'tenant.onmicrosoft.com',
      clientId: 'app-id',
      signInSignUpPolicy: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/my_tenant/policy/',
      passwordResetPolicy: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/my_tenanat/my_pr_policy/',
      scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read'],
      redirectUri: 'http://theredirect.uri',
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      graphUrl: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0',
    };

    /**
       * @returns {Promise<any>}
       */
      accessToken() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            const accessToken = await this.userAgent.acquireTokenSilent(config.scopes);
            resolve(accessToken);
          } catch (exception) {
            reject(exception);
            // this.userAgent.acquireTokenRedirect(config.scopes).then(resolve, reject);
          }
        });
      }

     /**
       * @param endpoint
       * @returns {AxiosPromise<any>}
       */
      async get(endpoint) {
        const accessToken = await this.accessToken();


        const requestConfig = {
          headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken },
        };

        const url = config.graphUrl + "/" + endpoint;
        return axios.get(url, requestConfig);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graph API is only accessible for Azure AD "normal" users and applications. Meaning - none of the B2C users, which are also called `local` will work with the GraphAPI.

If you need to work with the graph API on B2C, your only chance is to use an application identity for an application registered with the "normal" Azure AD part of your B2C tenant - [more info and detailed description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

Please also note that Microsoft Graph is not available for B2C users.